# Javascript: If statement won't work with setInterval in function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, setinterval

I want a function to run every 1 second where it loops through these four cases.
It won't do anything. Here's the code.

```
    var countX = 1;
    setInterval(finalBattle, 1000);
    function finalBattle() {
        switch (countX) 
        case 1:
            elemAttack.innerHTML = finalCut[counter];
            counter++;
            countX++;
            break;
        case 2:
            elemComment.innerHTML = finalCut[counter];
            counter++;
            countX++;
            break;
        case 3:
            elemDefense.innerHTML = finalCut[counter];
            counter++;
            countX++;
            break;
        case 4:
            elemComment.innerHTML = finalCut[counter];
            counter++;
            countX = 1;
            break;
    }
```

I've checked and the problem is not elemAttack or the finalcut array.

Comment: Not only that, but `var countX = 1; if(countX == 2)` still won't work as expected. You need to move `countX` further up the scope

Comment: Where is the `if` statement? *"It won't do anything"* So it does not even call `finalBattle`?

Comment: Also, it's a good practice to declare a function before using it. This is not the case, you should declare finalBattle() before it's assignment is setInterval()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch needs to wrap the case statements in a `{}`

[switch statement mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

so it will be

```
var countX = 1;
setInterval(finalBattle, 1000);
function finalBattle() {
    switch (countX) {
      case 1:
          elemAttack.innerHTML = finalCut[counter];
          counter++;
          countX++;
          break;
      case 2:
          elemComment.innerHTML = finalCut[counter];
          counter++;
          countX++;
          break;
      case 3:
          elemDefense.innerHTML = finalCut[counter];
          counter++;
          countX++;
          break;
      case 4:
          elemComment.innerHTML = finalCut[counter];
          counter++;
          countX = 1;
          break;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should use `==` (equality), not `=` (assignment).

Change:

```
if (countX = 2) {
```

To:

```
if (countX == 2) {
```